# General enquiry about jquery slider behavior

Tags: jquery

I was working on a free gallery slider from the internet and that works fine but what my client need is completely out of my mind.I will explain it you guys.

1. There are four albums(these can get extended) as a thumbnail of the slider.
2. Each of these albums will contain a certain amount of images.
3. User clicks on album 1 the 1st image in the album should show up and when user clicks on next button he should remain in the same album and when he reaches the last image while scrolling the next button should take him to first image.
4. When the user clicks on gallery 2 the same thing should happen like gallery 1.

I just need to know if this is possible or not.If it is I would need a direction from where can i find one.

Here is [link](http://s21.postimage.org/6lwkfynnb/gallery.jpg) of an image of how the gallery slider will look.

Answer (score 0):

[this](http://www.tn3gallery.com/?refCode=fe8775) jquery might help you..

search over net or jst google it.. may options will be available to you..

Comment: please refer to the image provided in the link.I have searched but did not find what i am looking for.

Comment: if the requirements are sticky then its hard to find exact jquery.. another option -try to create your own.. ;)